# Title/Text In Event (marker) Tooltip?

Tags: highcharts

I switched from v2 to v3 and when I use to hover over an event (marker) a tooltip would appear and it would have text that I wrote in show up.

Now that I am on v3 I don't see this text show up anymore, I only see the date.

Is this still possible?

Comment: Can you give a demo or explain it better ?

Comment: Please recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You can use a the tooltip formatter:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return "My custom Text";
        }
    }
```

[Highcharts API Tooltip Formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)

Comment: Ya I saw that and tried that, It did not work. I will try again maybe I did something wrong.